# How can I use jQuery to make an image fade on a hover?

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseevent, fadeto

I've tried looking at my code over and over again to have the octo image fade on mouse hover with no luck. This is a rookie question but wondering if someone greater than I can take a peek.

Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/bennett_up/rybc238w/

```
$('#octo').hover(function(){  
$(this).find('img').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0);},  
function(){  
$(this).find('img').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);  
});
```

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fiddle, I see that the image itself is '#octo' and not a child of it, therefore you don't need the .find('img') as follows:

```
$('#octo').hover(function(){  
   $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0);  
},  
function(){  
  $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);  
});
```

HTML for reference:

```
<ul id="contact">
    <li><img id="octo" src="http://s.icons8.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/octopus-128.png" width="28" height="28"></li>
</ul>
```

And here's a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/d6t0waoj/

Comment: Thanks all, this is super helpful. Part of my issue is that on JSFiddle I wasn't in the right Frameworks (needs to be jQuery 2.1.3). Do I need to load that library in my html before I load the script? <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes Bennet_up, you need to include it before the code for any jQuery to work, I did have to do that in the fiddle and forgot to mention that. This applies to whenever you see something like jQuery() or $()

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.find('img')` since `$(this)` already refers to the image element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $('#octo').hover(function(){  
      $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0); },  
   function(){  
      $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);  
   });
```

This will solve you problem